# Question about stabilizers in abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

> Show that for $g \in G$ and $x \in X$ one has $\mathrm{Stab}_G(g*x)=g\,\mathrm{Stab}_G(x)g^{-1}$

Approach: Show

$$\mathrm{Stab}_G(g*x) \subseteq g\,\mathrm{Stab}_G(x)g^{-1}$$ 
$$g\,\mathrm{Stab}_G(x)g^{-1} \subseteq \mathrm{Stab}_G(g*x)$$

Let $p \in \mathrm{Stab}_G(g*x)$, so

$$p*(g*x)=g*x$$

$$(pg)*x=g*x$$

$$g^{-1}*(pg*x)=g^{-1}*(g*x)$$

$$g^{-1}pg*(x)=x,$$

so

$$g^{-1}pg \in \mathrm{Stab}_G(x)$$

which implies $$p \in g\,\mathrm{Stab}_G(x)g^{-1}$$

How does this look?

Let $p \in g\,\mathrm{Stab}_G(x)g^{-1}$, I am not quite sure how to handle this side. Can I just go backwards?

Comment: $g^{-1}pg \in \mathrm{Stab}_G(x) \implies g^{-1}p \in \mathrm{Stab}_G(x) g^{-1} \implies p \in g\mathrm{Stab}_G(x) g^{-1}$

Answer (score 1):

I find the other implication easier since $p \in gG_xg^{-1} \implies p*(g*x) = (ghg^{-1}g)*x = g*(h*x) = g*x$ where $h \in G_x$